# ExtJS 4 button next

Tags: button, focus, extjs4

Problem is probably simple but I can't find the proper answer.

I have a panel with only four buttons. Just vbox with buttons. And now I want to select and press this buttons not only with mouse click but also via keyboard. So I used Ext.KeyMap and I catch every key I want to: ENTER, TAB, DOWN and UP. But I can't find simple way to move focus betveen this buttons.

E.g. I'm focused on first button, press DOWN key and I want to be focused on the second button. No way. I tried

```
but1.down('button[action=next]').focus(false, 100))
```

but it can't work. Be so kind as to prompt please.

---

Well what can I say, just VERY BIG thank you – it is working obviously.

I had no idea to use KeyNav.
But it’s working in such a simple example My case is a little bit more complicated and I asked this question just simplified my situation. So this menu is the second screen in my application and it is constructed in such a way:

```
PANEL
    Panel1
        Label1
        Button 1
        Button 2
        Button 3
    Panel2
        Label2
        Button 4
        Button 5
    Panel3
        Label3
        Button 6
        Button 7
    Button 8
```

and every user can see (panels are hidden on the start) and use parts of this structure (e.g. Panel1, 3 and Button 8). I decide about it one step before (login step) and I show to the user menu only for him in the container defined:

```
    Ext.define('Gromel.view.Menu', {
        extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
        requires:[
            'Ext.tab.Panel',
            'Ext.layout.container.Border',
            'Ext.form.Label',
            'Ext.form.Panel'
        ],

        xtype:      'app-menu',

        fullscreen: true,
        layout:     'fit',
...
```

I place your code on the PANEL level and it's working almost properly. And I use the following default definition for above items:

```
defaults: {
    margin:  '0 0 10 0',
    baseCls: 'x-btn-default-large',
    cls:     'cap-btn',
    style:   'font-size:18px;text-align: center',
    height:  40,
    width:   '50%',
// yours:
    handler: function () {
        this.up('panel').activeButton = this.activeIndex;
    }
}
```

so I modified your cls change method to:

```
button[method]('x-focus x-btn-focus x-btn-default-large-focus')
```

and your procedure is working.

Problems I can't manage now are:

- as you see on the same level as buttons I have labels and I don't know how to bypass them;
- more important - I want to run this procedure only on menu panel not in login panel and the rest (deeper in my structure) but this is global, so if I press ENTER on login panel I see the effect on next, menu panel; I replaced ENTER effect in the following way (I want to press ENTER on every button in menu and run different presses events):

  case e.ENTER: butt.fireEvent('click', butt);  break;

So if it isn’t to much for you be so kind and prompt me more please.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use ExtJS [KeyNav](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyNav).

**KeyNav** provides a convenient wrapper for normalized keyboard navigation. KeyNav allows you to bind navigation keys to function calls that will get called when the keys are pressed, providing an easy way to implement custom navigation schemes for any UI component.

As you said

> I have a panel with only four buttons.

I have work around that, I have created an small [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29ge) demo. It will show you how is working. I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

You can also refer this **[Key Navigation Sample](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/keynav/keynav.html)**

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Button Example with keyNav',
    margin: 10,
    bodyStyle: {
        'border-width': '2px'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center'
    },
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'button',
        height: 50,
        width: '70%',
        margin: '20 0',
        handler: function () {
            this.up('panel').activeButton = this.activeIndex;
        }
    },
    items: [{
        text: 'My button 1',
        activeIndex: 0
    }, {
        text: 'My button 2',
        activeIndex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'My button 3',
        activeIndex: 2
    }, {
        text: 'My button 4',
        activeIndex: 3
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
            var panel = this;
            panel.keynav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', {
                target: Ext.getBody(),
                scope: panel,
                up: panel.doFocusOnButton,
                down: panel.doFocusOnButton,
                enter: panel.doFocusOnButton,
                tab: panel.doFocusOnButton
            });
            //Remove cls on panel click
            panel.el.on('click', function () {
                this.doAddRemoveCls('removeCls');
            }, panel)
            panel.focus();
        }
    },

    /*
     * Common event will fire on key : ENTER, TAB, UP, DOWN
     * @param {Ext.EventObject} e Just as Ext.Element wraps around a native DOM node
     */
    doFocusOnButton: function (e) { //{ http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.EventObject }
        var panel = this,
            button = '',
            totalItem = panel.items.length - 1;
        if (Ext.isDefined(panel.activeButton) == false) {
            panel.activeButton = 0;
        } else {
            this.doAddRemoveCls('removeCls');
            switch (e.getKey()) {
            case e.ENTER:
            case e.DOWN:
            case e.TAB:
                panel.activeButton++;
                if (panel.activeButton > totalItem) {
                    panel.activeButton = 0;
                }
                break;
            case e.UP:
                panel.activeButton--;
                if (panel.activeButton < 0) {
                    panel.activeButton = totalItem;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        this.doAddRemoveCls('addCls');
    },
    //This function will add or remove cls..
    doAddRemoveCls: function (method) {
        var panel = this,
            index = panel.activeButton,
            button = Ext.isDefined(index) ? panel.down('[activeIndex=' + index + ']') : null;

        if (button) {
            button[method]('x-focus x-btn-focus x-btn-default-small-focus')
        }
    }
});
```